# Can't run python program in terminal

Tags: 12.04, python, spyder

(I am using ubuntu 12.04)

I made this python program:

```
#!/bin/sh
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Created on Tue Nov 12 19:44:50 2013

#@author: matthew

import os

print "Multiple Command Runner"
print "<Made by Matthew Cherrey>"
print "-------------------------"
numbcommand = 0
allcoms = []
while 1:
    numbcommand = numbcommand + 1
    command = raw_input(" Command: ")
    allcoms.append(command)
    decide = raw_input("Press [Enter] to and another command, press [r] to run all commands: ")
    if decide == "r":
        break

commands = ""
first = True
for item in allcoms:
    if first:
        commands = item
    else:
        commands = commands + " && " + item
os.system(commands)
```

And I want to be able to run it in the terminal. I use the python editor: [Spyder](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/) This has an option to "Run in system terminal". Whenever I do this, my program works perfectly. I can enter multiple commands, and have them all run. When I set the file to an exicutible and run `/home/matthew/.runallcommands.py --python` or `/home/matthew/.runallcommands.py`, first makes my cursor into a "t" which then when I click somewere, is take a picture of that area of the screen and saves it as a photo named "OS" in my home folder. then I get this error message:

```
matthew@matthew-MS-7721:~$ /home/matthew/.runallcommands.py --python
Warning: unknown mime-type for "Multiple Command Runner" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "Multiple Command Runner"
Warning: unknown mime-type for "<Made by Matthew Cherrey>" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "<Made by Matthew Cherrey>"
/home/matthew/.runallcommands.py: 13: /home/matthew/.runallcommands.py: numbcommand: not found
/home/matthew/.runallcommands.py: 14: /home/matthew/.runallcommands.py: allcoms: not found
/home/matthew/.runallcommands.py: 17: /home/matthew/.runallcommands.py: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "do")
```

I am not sure if it has something to do with how I called the file, because my program worked 100% fine in the terminal in spyder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your python commands are being interpreted as shell commands e.g. `print "Multiple Command Runner"` is looking for a *file* of that name to print (with an associated MIME type).

As far as I know, adding a `--python` command line parameter to a shell script does not cause it to be interpreted as a python script - to do that, you must change the `#!/bin/sh` 'shebang' to an appropriate python shebang e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Created on Tue Nov 12 19:44:50 2013

#@author: matthew

import os
.
.
.
```

You will then be able to run it by making the file executable

```
chmod +x /path/to/yourfile.py
```

and execute it as

```
/path/to/yourfile.py
```

If `yourfile.py` is in the current directory, you can use the relative path `./yourfile.py` to execute it.

Comment: The screenshot is taken because `import os` runs the command `import` which belongs zu ImageMagick and takes a screenshot.